# Square brackets at the end of TFBertModel call method

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensor, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to understand how to use bert-base-cased pretrained model in my code, so I was reviewing this code:

```
input_ids = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_ids")

input_mask = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="attention_mask")

embeddings = bert(input_ids, attention_mask = input_mask)[0]
```

and I couldn't figure out what the square brackets at the end of the embeddings line means

this how the model is declared:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer,TFBertModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
bert = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
```

I looked in:
https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.9.2/model_doc/bert.html#bert

and I found in the documentation of the call method for [TFBertForNextSentencePrediction](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.9.2/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.TFBertForNextSentencePrediction.call) this example:

```
1 >>> import tensorflow as tf

2 >>> from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertForNextSentencePrediction

3 >>> tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

4 >>> model = TFBertForNextSentencePrediction.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

5 >>> prompt = "In Italy, pizza served in formal settings, such as at a restaurant, is presented unsliced."

6 >>> next_sentence = "The sky is blue due to the shorter wavelength of blue light."

7 >>> encoding = tokenizer(prompt, next_sentence, return_tensors='tf')

8 >>> logits = model(encoding['input_ids'], token_type_ids=encoding['token_type_ids'])[0]

9 >>> assert logits[0][0] < logits[0][1] # the next sentence was random
```

which also used the square brackets (in the 8th line) with no explanation of what they do.